# query elasticsearch right after saving data with spring can be not up to date?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, elasticsearch, real-time

i have the following code:
(threads can access `synchronized(someObj)` for specific obj only one at a time.)

```
@Async
public void funcA() {
 synchronized (someObj) {
      //query (using spring) for **some_data_in_ES**
      //check if **some_data_in_ES** is not 'nothing'
      //update **some_data_in_ES** to be 'A' using spring 
 }
}

@Async
public void funcB() {
 synchronized (someObj) {
      //query (using spring) for **some_data_in_ES**
      //check if **some_data_in_ES** is not 'nothing'
      //update **some_data_in_ES** to be 'B' using spring
 }
}
```

if funcA got control over `synchronized(someObj)` and update **some_data_in_ES** to be 'A' and when lock on `synchronized(someObj)` is free, funcB steped into `synchronized(someObj)` and checked if **some_data_in_ES** is not 'nothing'.
is there a chance that B will get 'nothing' or elasticsearch will only return **some_data_in_ES** after it updated to be 'A'?

Comment: You have two `funcA` - is the 2nd one supposed to be `funcB'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a chance that B will get 'nothing' or elasticsearch will only return some_data_in_ES after it updated to be 'A'?

Yes B can see either 'nothing' or 'A'.  Updates to ES are not atomic.  How quickly you will see the update depends on how ES and Lucene are configured.  So it's all a matter of timing and configuration.  One way I've dealt with issues in the past is to use an ID from the database I'm indexing in ES.  That way I can be sure it's unique and it's trivial to write upserts and updates with.

Checkout the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#docs-update), for example an upsert might be appropriate.

Read up on [near real-time search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html) for more information on when documents become visible.  In particular note the refresh interval and the refresh API.

Comment: Thanks! Your information was helpful and helped solving the problem.